# How do I retrieve disk information in C#?

Tags: c#, disk

I would like to access information on the logical drives on my computer using C#. How should I accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 78, accepted):

For most information, you can use the [DriveInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx) class.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Info {
    public static void Main() {
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives) {
            //There are more attributes you can use.
            //Check the MSDN link for a complete example.
            Console.WriteLine(drive.Name);
            if (drive.IsReady) Console.WriteLine(drive.TotalSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about drive info on a machine other than the local machine?

Comment: For network mounted drives this works, reports drive type as "Network". For remote querying, I think you should ask a different question.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to get information for **single/specific drive** at your local machine. You can do it as follow using [DriveInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx) class:

```
//C Drive Path, this is useful when you are about to find a Drive root from a Location Path.
string path = "C:\\Windows";

//Find its root directory i.e "C:\\"
string rootDir = Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(path);

//Get all information of Drive i.e C
DriveInfo driveInfo = new DriveInfo(rootDir); //you can pass Drive path here e.g   DriveInfo("C:\\")

long availableFreeSpace = driveInfo.AvailableFreeSpace;
string driveFormat = driveInfo.DriveFormat;
string name = driveInfo.Name;
long totalSize = driveInfo.TotalSize;
```

Answer (score 6):

What about mounted volumes, where you have no drive letter?

```
foreach( ManagementObject volume in 
             new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Volume" ).Get())
{
  if( volume["FreeSpace"] != null )
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1} out of {2}",
                  volume["Name"],
                  ulong.Parse(volume["FreeSpace"].ToString()).ToString("#,##0"),
                  ulong.Parse(volume["Capacity"].ToString()).ToString("#,##0"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Just found it myself:
''foreach( ManagementObject volume in new ManagementObjectSearcher( "Select * from Win32_Volume" ).Get() ) { if( volume["FreeSpace"] != null ) { Console.WriteLine( "{0} = {1} out of {2}", volume["Name"], ulong.Parse( volume["FreeSpace"].ToString() ).ToString( "#,##0" ), ulong.Parse( volume["Capacity"].ToString() ).ToString( "#,##0" ) ); } } }

Answer (score 5):

Use System.IO.DriveInfo class
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Check the [DriveInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx) Class and see if it contains all the info that you need.

Answer (score 2):

In ASP .NET Core 3.1, if you want to get code that works both on windows and on linux, you can get your drives as follows:

```
var drives = DriveInfo
    .GetDrives()
    .Where(d => d.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
    .Where(d => d.IsReady)
    .ToArray();
```

If you don't apply both wheres, you are going to get many drives if you run the code in linux (e.g. "/dev", "/sys", "/etc/hosts", etc.).

This is specially useful when developing an app to work in a Linux Docker container.