# Get free disk space

Tags: c#, diskspace

Given each of the inputs below, I'd like to get free space on that location. Something like

```
long GetFreeSpace(string path)
```

Inputs:

```
c:

c:\

c:\temp

\\server

\\server\C\storage
```

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412632

Comment: Not a duplicate, the stackoverflow.com/questions/412632 only asks about disks, I also ask about UNC paths and the solution in 412632 doesn't work for them.

Answer (score 87):

this works for me...

```
using System.IO;

private long GetTotalFreeSpace(string driveName)
{
    foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
    {
        if (drive.IsReady && drive.Name == driveName)
        {
            return drive.TotalFreeSpace;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: `drive.TotalFreeSpace` doesn't work for me but `drive.AvailableFreeSpace` does

Comment: I know this answer is ancient, but you usually need to use `AvailableFreeSpace` as @knocte says. `AvailableFreeSpace` lists how much is actually available for the user (due to quotos). `TotalFreeSpace` lists what is available on the disk, irregardless of what the user can use.

Comment: I upvoted @RoyT's comment because he took the time to explain why one is recommended over the other.

Comment: this is working well for me (modulo the 'availableSpace' comments), but a simpler and more robust approach would seem to be to [create a new DriveInfo from the driveName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.-ctor?view=net-5.0), rather than iterating over everything and checking for a matching name.

Answer (score 44):

Working code snippet using `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` from link by RichardOD.

```
// Pinvoke for API function
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(string lpDirectoryName,
out ulong lpFreeBytesAvailable,
out ulong lpTotalNumberOfBytes,
out ulong lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes);

public static bool DriveFreeBytes(string folderName, out ulong freespace)
{
    freespace = 0;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderName))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("folderName");
    }

    if (!folderName.EndsWith("\\"))
    {
        folderName += '\\';
    }

    ulong free = 0, dummy1 = 0, dummy2 = 0;

    if (GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(folderName, out free, out dummy1, out dummy2))
    {
        freespace = free;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd rather have it return void, like `... if (!GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(folderName, out free, out total, out dummy)) throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());`. Quite convenient to find the code here anyway.

Comment: It doesn't need to end with `"\\"`. It can be any existing dir path or even just `C:`. Here is my version of this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58005966/964478

Answer (score 42):

[DriveInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx) will help you with some of those (but it doesn't work with UNC paths), but really I think you will need to use [GetDiskFreeSpaceEx](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.GetDiskFreeSpaceEx). You can probably achieve some functionality with WMI. GetDiskFreeSpaceEx looks like your best bet.

Chances are you will probably have to clean up your paths to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 8):

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

        foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("  Drive type: {0}", d.DriveType);
            if (d.IsReady == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel);
                Console.WriteLine("  File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat);
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "  Available space to current user:{0, 15} bytes", 
                    d.AvailableFreeSpace);

                Console.WriteLine(
                    "  Total available space:          {0, 15} bytes",
                    d.TotalFreeSpace);

                Console.WriteLine(
                    "  Total size of drive:            {0, 15} bytes ",
                    d.TotalSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
/* 
This code produces output similar to the following:

Drive A:\
  Drive type: Removable
Drive C:\
  Drive type: Fixed
  Volume label: 
  File system: FAT32
  Available space to current user:     4770430976 bytes
  Total available space:               4770430976 bytes
  Total size of drive:                10731683840 bytes 
Drive D:\
  Drive type: Fixed
  Volume label: 
  File system: NTFS
  Available space to current user:    15114977280 bytes
  Total available space:              15114977280 bytes
  Total size of drive:                25958948864 bytes 
Drive E:\
  Drive type: CDRom

The actual output of this code will vary based on machine and the permissions
granted to the user executing it.
*/
```

Comment: While this code does in fact work for all drives on a system, it doesn't address the OP's requirement for mount points and junction points and shares...

Answer (score 6):

Here is a refactored and simplified version of the @sasha_gud answer:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(string lpDirectoryName,
        out ulong lpFreeBytesAvailable,
        out ulong lpTotalNumberOfBytes,
        out ulong lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes);

    public static ulong GetDiskFreeSpace(string path)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
        }

        ulong dummy = 0;

        if (!GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(path, out ulong freeSpace, out dummy, out dummy))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }

        return freeSpace;
    }
```

Comment: Your way is better, given you extracting the LastWin32Error

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the size in GB, so I just improved the code from Superman above with the following changes:

```
public double GetTotalHDDSize(string driveName)
{
    foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
    {
        if (drive.IsReady && drive.Name == driveName)
        {
            return drive.TotalSize / (1024 * 1024 * 1024);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You are returning total capacity of the drive.

Comment: I thought that anyone can calculate GB having bytes, but you shown that was wrong asumption. Tis code is wrong as division uses `long` but function returns `double`.

Answer (score 4):

Check this out (this is a working solution for me)

```
public long AvailableFreeSpace()
{
    long longAvailableFreeSpace = 0;
    try{
        DriveInfo[] arrayOfDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (var d in arrayOfDrives)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("  Drive type: {0}", d.DriveType);
            if (d.IsReady == true && d.Name == "/data")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel);
                Console.WriteLine("File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat);
                Console.WriteLine("AvailableFreeSpace for current user:{0, 15} bytes",d.AvailableFreeSpace);
                Console.WriteLine("TotalFreeSpace {0, 15} bytes",d.TotalFreeSpace);
                Console.WriteLine("Total size of drive: {0, 15} bytes \n",d.TotalSize);
                }
                longAvailableFreeSpaceInMB = d.TotalFreeSpace;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ServiceLocator.GetInsightsProvider()?.LogError(ex);
    }
    return longAvailableFreeSpace;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

untested:

```
using System;
using System.Management;

ManagementObject disk = new
ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid="c:"");
disk.Get();
Console.WriteLine("Logical Disk Size = " + disk["Size"] + " bytes");
Console.WriteLine("Logical Disk FreeSpace = " + disk["FreeSpace"] + "
bytes");
```

Btw what is the outcome of free diskspace on c:\temp ? you will get the space free of c:\

Comment: As Kenny says, the free space for any given directory is not necessarily the same as the free space for the drive of the root directory. Certainly isn't on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
var driveName = "C:\\";
var freeSpace = DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(x => x.Name == driveName && x.IsReady).FirstOrDefault().TotalFreeSpace;
```

Good luck

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks Xiawi, this answer is shorter and cleaner than other answers, and works for me.

Answer (score 2):

see this [article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/windowsservices/article.php/c12357/C-Map-Network-Drive-API.htm)!

1. identify UNC par or local drive path by searching index of ":"
2. if its is UNC PATH you cam map  UNC path
3. code to execute drive name is mapped drive name < UNC Mapped Drive or Local Drive>.

   ```
   using System.IO;

   private long GetTotalFreeSpace(string driveName)
   {
   foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
   {
       if (drive.IsReady && drive.Name == driveName)
       {
           return drive.TotalFreeSpace;
       }
   }
   return -1;
   }
   ```
4. unmap after you requirement done.

Comment: While this code does in fact work for all drives on a system, it doesn't address the OP's requirement for mount points and junction points...

Answer (score 2):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465187/get-available-disk-free-space-for-a-given-path-on-windows?answertab=votes#tab-top) and @RichardOD suggested , you should do like this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(string lpDirectoryName,
   out ulong lpFreeBytesAvailable,
   out ulong lpTotalNumberOfBytes,
   out ulong lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes);

ulong FreeBytesAvailable;
ulong TotalNumberOfBytes;
ulong TotalNumberOfFreeBytes;

bool success = GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(@"\\mycomputer\myfolder",
                                  out FreeBytesAvailable,
                                  out TotalNumberOfBytes,
                                  out TotalNumberOfFreeBytes);
if(!success)
    throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();

Console.WriteLine("Free Bytes Available:      {0,15:D}", FreeBytesAvailable);
Console.WriteLine("Total Number Of Bytes:     {0,15:D}", TotalNumberOfBytes);
Console.WriteLine("Total Number Of FreeBytes: {0,15:D}", TotalNumberOfFreeBytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted a similar method for my project but in my case the input paths were either from local disk volumes or clustered storage volumes (CSVs). So DriveInfo class did not work for me. CSVs have a mount point under another drive, typically C:\ClusterStorage\Volume*. Note that C: will be a different Volume than C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1

This is what I finally came up with:

```
    public static ulong GetFreeSpaceOfPathInBytes(string path)
    {
        if ((new Uri(path)).IsUnc)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Cannot find free space for UNC path " + path);
        }

        ulong freeSpace = 0;
        int prevVolumeNameLength = 0;

        foreach (ManagementObject volume in
                new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Volume").Get())
        {
            if (UInt32.Parse(volume["DriveType"].ToString()) > 1 &&                             // Is Volume monuted on host
                volume["Name"] != null &&                                                       // Volume has a root directory
                path.StartsWith(volume["Name"].ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)  // Required Path is under Volume's root directory 
                )
            {
                // If multiple volumes have their root directory matching the required path,
                // one with most nested (longest) Volume Name is given preference.
                // Case: CSV volumes monuted under other drive volumes.

                int currVolumeNameLength = volume["Name"].ToString().Length;

                if ((prevVolumeNameLength == 0 || currVolumeNameLength > prevVolumeNameLength) &&
                    volume["FreeSpace"] != null
                    )
                {
                    freeSpace = ulong.Parse(volume["FreeSpace"].ToString());
                    prevVolumeNameLength = volume["Name"].ToString().Length;
                }
            }
        }

        if (prevVolumeNameLength > 0)
        {
            return freeSpace;
        }

        throw new Exception("Could not find Volume Information for path " + path);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and i saw waruna manjula giving the best answer.
However writing it all down on the console is not what you might want.
To get string off al info use the following

Step one: declare values at begin

```
    //drive 1
    public static string drivename = "";
    public static string drivetype = "";
    public static string drivevolumelabel = "";
    public static string drivefilesystem = "";
    public static string driveuseravailablespace = "";
    public static string driveavailablespace = "";
    public static string drivetotalspace = "";

    //drive 2
    public static string drivename2 = "";
    public static string drivetype2 = "";
    public static string drivevolumelabel2 = "";
    public static string drivefilesystem2 = "";
    public static string driveuseravailablespace2 = "";
    public static string driveavailablespace2 = "";
    public static string drivetotalspace2 = "";

    //drive 3
    public static string drivename3 = "";
    public static string drivetype3 = "";
    public static string drivevolumelabel3 = "";
    public static string drivefilesystem3 = "";
    public static string driveuseravailablespace3 = "";
    public static string driveavailablespace3 = "";
    public static string drivetotalspace3 = "";
```

Step 2: actual code

```
                DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
                int drive = 1;
                foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
                {
                    if (drive == 1)
                    {
                        drivename = String.Format("Drive {0}", d.Name);
                        drivetype = String.Format("Drive type: {0}", d.DriveType);
                        if (d.IsReady == true)
                        {
                            drivevolumelabel = String.Format("Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel);
                            drivefilesystem = String.Format("File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat);
                            driveuseravailablespace = String.Format("Available space to current user:{0, 15} bytes", d.AvailableFreeSpace);
                            driveavailablespace = String.Format("Total available space:{0, 15} bytes", d.TotalFreeSpace);
                            drivetotalspace = String.Format("Total size of drive:{0, 15} bytes ", d.TotalSize);
                        }
                        drive = 2;
                    }
                    else if (drive == 2)
                    {
                        drivename2 = String.Format("Drive {0}", d.Name);
                        drivetype2 = String.Format("Drive type: {0}", d.DriveType);
                        if (d.IsReady == true)
                        {
                            drivevolumelabel2 = String.Format("Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel);
                            drivefilesystem2 = String.Format("File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat);
                            driveuseravailablespace2 = String.Format("Available space to current user:{0, 15} bytes", d.AvailableFreeSpace);
                            driveavailablespace2 = String.Format("Total available space:{0, 15} bytes", d.TotalFreeSpace);
                            drivetotalspace2 = String.Format("Total size of drive:{0, 15} bytes ", d.TotalSize);
                        }
                        drive = 3;
                    }
                    else if (drive == 3)
                    {
                        drivename3 = String.Format("Drive {0}", d.Name);
                        drivetype3 = String.Format("Drive type: {0}", d.DriveType);
                        if (d.IsReady == true)
                        {
                            drivevolumelabel3 = String.Format("Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel);
                            drivefilesystem3 = String.Format("File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat);
                            driveuseravailablespace3 = String.Format("Available space to current user:{0, 15} bytes", d.AvailableFreeSpace);
                            driveavailablespace3 = String.Format("Total available space:{0, 15} bytes", d.TotalFreeSpace);
                            drivetotalspace3 = String.Format("Total size of drive:{0, 15} bytes ", d.TotalSize);
                        }
                        drive = 4;
                    }
                    if (drive == 4)
                    {
                        drive = 1;
                    }
                }

                //part 2: possible debug - displays in output

                //drive 1
                Console.WriteLine(drivename);
                Console.WriteLine(drivetype);
                Console.WriteLine(drivevolumelabel);
                Console.WriteLine(drivefilesystem);
                Console.WriteLine(driveuseravailablespace);
                Console.WriteLine(driveavailablespace);
                Console.WriteLine(drivetotalspace);

                //drive 2
                Console.WriteLine(drivename2);
                Console.WriteLine(drivetype2);
                Console.WriteLine(drivevolumelabel2);
                Console.WriteLine(drivefilesystem2);
                Console.WriteLine(driveuseravailablespace2);
                Console.WriteLine(driveavailablespace2);
                Console.WriteLine(drivetotalspace2);

                //drive 3
                Console.WriteLine(drivename3);
                Console.WriteLine(drivetype3);
                Console.WriteLine(drivevolumelabel3);
                Console.WriteLine(drivefilesystem3);
                Console.WriteLine(driveuseravailablespace3);
                Console.WriteLine(driveavailablespace3);
                Console.WriteLine(drivetotalspace3);
```

I want to note that you can just make all the console writelines comment code, but i thought it would be nice for you to test it.
If you display all these after each other you get the same list as waruna majuna

Drive C:\
Drive type: Fixed
Volume label: 
File system: NTFS
Available space to current user:   134880153600 bytes
Total available space:   134880153600 bytes
Total size of drive:   499554185216 bytes

Drive D:\
Drive type: CDRom

Drive H:\
Drive type: Fixed
Volume label: HDD
File system: NTFS
Available space to current user:  2000010817536 bytes
Total available space:  2000010817536 bytes
Total size of drive:  2000263573504 bytes

However you can now acces all of the loose information at strings

Comment: Not creating a class for 3 simular objects and using an else if. I cried a little.

Comment: Sorry boiler plating code, not using collections and not using a switch?