# Programmatically determining space available from UNC Path

Tags: .net, winapi, wmi

Is there a programmatic API for determining available space on NAS storage from a UNC path? I looked through the WMI documentation and it wasn't clear that this is possible.

A code example and references to the relevant API calls would be much appreciated.

Comment: in case a mod sees this, this should probably be marked a duplicate of 61037184.  Yes this question came first but that one has an actual implementation of the only upvoted answer here and bringing in dll's is non-trivial so those details are pertinent.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Using [this example](http://blog.palelocust.com/?p=7) on how to get the UNC path, you could just return the FreeSpace property, I've modified the code below:

```
ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath(@"\" + System.Environment.MachineName + @"\root\cimv2");
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("select * from Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType = 4");
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(path, new ConnectionOptions());
ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

foreach (ManagementObject o in search.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine(o.Properties["FreeSpace"].Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I think this only works if the UNC path is already 'mapped' to a logical disk (with drive letter, e.g. Z:). What if you want to check free space on a server that is not mapped?

Answer (score 4):

In the windows API, [GetFreeDiskSpaceEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393711/c-get-free-disk-space) seems to be the method to use, which works on UNC paths according to the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364937(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: GetDiskFreeSpaceEx isn't available in VB.Net. How do you achieve finding free space on a UNC path in VB.Net (not C!)

Comment: @Tym you can call into Windows dlls using the .Net DllImport infrastructure