# Get Operating system,disk space of connected computers windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, cpu-usage, diskspace

Using c# I want to get OS name, disk space, CPU usage of the connected machine to my server.
I can get connected machine name by using the following code

```
foreach (DirectoryEntry computers in root.Children)
{
   foreach (DirectoryEntry computer in computers.Children)
   {                 
     if (computer.Name != "Schema")
     {                           
       string value = computer.Name;                    
     }
   }
}
```

But don't know to get **OS name**, **disk space**, **CPU usage** of connected machines

Comment: an alternative for your consideration - powershell: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2010/02/04/inventorying-computers-with-ad-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

**OS name**

Add a .NET reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic. Then call:

```
new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo().OSFullName
```

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.computerinfo.osfullname?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#Microsoft_VisualBasic_Devices_ComputerInfo_OSFullName):

> This property returns detailed information about the operating system
>   name if Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) is installed on the
>   computer. Otherwise, this property returns the same string as the
>   My.Computer.Info.OSPlatform property, which provides less detailed
>   information than WMI can provide.information than WMI can provide.

**Disk space**

```
    private  long GetTotalFreeSpace(string driveName)
    {
        foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            if (drive.IsReady && drive.Name == driveName)
            {
                return drive.TotalSize;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

**CPU usage**

You can use the [PerformanceCounter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.computerinfo.osfullname?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#Microsoft_VisualBasic_Devices_ComputerInfo_OSFullName) class from [System.Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.aspx).

Initialize like this:

```
PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;

cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
```

Consume like this:

```
public string getCurrentCpuUsage(){
            return cpuCounter.NextValue()+"%";
}
```

**Referances**

**[How to get OS name?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13743986/4977870)**

**[How to get disk space?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6815482/4977870)**

**[How to get CPU usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/278088/4977870)**