# c# 2010 code for getting the free space of the HDD

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I retrieve disk information in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412632/how-do-i-retrieve-disk-information-in-c)

hi dudes.
I wanna a code in c# 2010 which gets the free space of the drive.

Comment: There is no such thing as `C# 2010` -- you probably mean C# 4 (which ships with Visual Studio 2010)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [DriveInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx) and use the property [TotalFreeSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.totalfreespace.aspx)