# .net c# code for detecting space on server for each drive

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I retrieve disk information in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412632/how-do-i-retrieve-disk-information-in-c)

- I need a **.net c# code** example to detect **each server's drive space**.
- I also want step by step implementation **instructions**.

Comment: I would rather teach you to fish, than giving you a fish. Which part of logic you are not able to sort out?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412632/how-do-i-retrieve-disk-information-in-c

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [**`DriveInfo.GetDrives`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives.aspx) method to retrieve an array of logical drives on a machine.

Example:

```
var nameAndFreeSpaceOfDrives = from drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives()
                               where drive.IsReady
                               select new { drive.Name, drive.TotalFreeSpace };
```

Answer (score 2):

You also can use management objects to obtain free space:

```
        using System.Management;
        .........
        ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"c:\"");
        disk.Get();
        MessageBox.Show(disk["FreeSpace"] + " bytes");
```

You also have to add reference to `System.Management` assembly manualy